# How to produce a noise spectrum from an rms velocity specification?

Tags: fft, noise, power-spectral-density, white-noise, rms

For a dynamic model I am looking at the appropriate input to analyse the performance under the influence of floor vibrations.
The norm is an ISO VC-C floor spectrum as displayed in the image. However, I am stuck in the derivation of going from a rms velocity to a (displacement) noise signal in the time domain. Any help on how to achieve this (in Matlab) would be greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Check out this answer https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/generating-time-domain-noise-from-psd?rq=1 . A potential idea: you may need to generate a time domain response for the velocity and then integrate it.